# Combinatorics ( colouring a checkerboard)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

If we identify colourings related by rotations of a checkerboard, how many ways can you paint it if it has 2Tx2T fields with m colours?

**My attempt:**

I'm struggling to begin this. The part of the question I am confused with is the "if we identify colourings related by rotations of a checkerboard".

Comment: Imagine if you will a checkerboard with only four squares and two colors, those colors being $0$ and $1$.  We consider the board $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ to be the "*same*" as the board $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ as well as $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ etc because the original board can simply be *rotated* to become exactly like the other boards.

Comment: With a $2\times 2$ board and $2$ colors we see that there are in effect only the six possible boards: $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.  Had rotations not been considered we would have had $2^4=16$ boards, but ten of those are considered duplicates.

Comment: As for an approach... look up "Burnside's Lemma" (*or more aptly named, "the lemma which is not burnside's"*) and "Polya's Enumeration Theorem."

Answer (score 1):

A solution that does not use Burnside's lemma explicitly:

There are $m^{4t^2}$ possible boards, and naively we must divide this by $4$. However:

- $m^{2t^2}$ boards are equivalent under a $180^\circ$ turn, so we must "boost" the count by $m^{2t^2}$ so that these boards are counted once (not $0.5$ times)
- $m^{t^2}$ boards are equivalent under a $90^\circ$ turn, so we must "boost" the count by $2m^{t^2}$ so that these boards are counted once (not $0.5$ times; before the first bullet point above they are counted $0.25$ times)

Thus the final answer is, writing $z=m^{t^2}$ (the number of ways to colour a fixed $t×t$ grid with $m$ colours),
$$\frac{z^4+z^2+2z}4$$

Comment: okay that helps a lot! is the t value related to the T in the question at all? or is it independent?

Comment: @MohammedG1 The $t$ here is exactly the $T$ in the question.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: I see you found the number of ways to colour a fixed t x t grid, would there be much difference if the grid was 2t x 2t? or would it be the same?

Comment: @MohammedG1 Just accept my answer already!